# How can I find childs of an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can you make it so that when I hover over a specific LI that text slides down.
I can't figure out how to detect a specific LI, only that I detect them all and the all slide down. 
https://jsfiddle.net/9rmmddpn/1/

```
var cl = $(".cl");
var clHover = $(".cl li");
var clExtra = $(".cl_extra");

function clHoverIn(c) {
    clHover.mouseenter(function() {
        cl.children(c).slideDown();
    })
    cl.children(c).slideDown();
}

function clHoverOut(c) {
    clHover.mouseenter(function() {
        cl.children(c).slideUp();
    })
}



$(clHover.children(1)).mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("log!");
});
```

Comment: Try to use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems overly complicated to achieve the desired result.

You can use the jQuery hover function, to define mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers.
https://api.jquery.com/hover/

The first function fires when you mouseover, the second one when you mouse out.

Inside these functions, `$(this)` will resolve to the item that you interacted with.

You can then target the desired element to slidedown or slideup.  For example: `$(this).find('.cl_extra').slideUp();`

```js
$(".cl li").hover(function(){
 $(this).find('.cl_extra').slideDown();
}, function(){
 $(this).find('.cl_extra').slideUp();
});
```

```css
/* Stand
***************************/

body {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
}

/***************************/

ul.cl {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
}

ul.cl li {
 width: 25%;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 background: #0EA4DB;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 10px 15px 25px grey;
  
  vertical-align: top;
}

ul.cl li h1 {
 font-size: 40px;
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

ul.cl li h2 {
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.cl li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.cl li span {
 color: #E8B928;
}

.cl_extra {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <ul class="cl">
  <li>
   <a href="#"><h1>Such News Much Wow</h1>
   <h2>Posted: 11-3-2017 by: <span>Dodge</span></h2></a>
   <p class="cl_extra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eleifend elit dapibus aliquet euismod. Pellentesque feugiat placerat orci, a pretium nisi rhoncus id. Proin accumsan purus lacus, vitae dapibus turpis interdum quis. Mauris nulla libero, tempor a quam vitae, volutpat dapibus enim. Nunc tempor elementum leo, quis ultricies mauris pretium at. Pellentesque augue enim, efficitur quis elit vitae, dapibus venenatis neque. Sed vel turpis libero.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><h1>Such CSS Much JS</h1>
   <h2>Posted: 11-3-2017 by: <span>Dodge</span></h2></a>
   <p class="cl_extra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eleifend elit dapibus aliquet euismod. Pellentesque feugiat placerat orci, a pretium nisi rhoncus id. Proin accumsan purus lacus, vitae dapibus turpis interdum quis. Mauris nulla libero, tempor a quam vitae, volutpat dapibus enim. Nunc tempor elementum leo, quis ultricies mauris pretium at. Pellentesque augue enim, efficitur quis elit vitae, dapibus venenatis neque. Sed vel turpis libero.</p>
  </li>
 </ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really overthinking it

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should do it on a certain selector.

Something like this:

```
$('.cl li').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $(this).children('p').slideDown();
}
$('.cl li').on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).children('p').slideUp();
}
```

Comment: Updated to slide effect